# Rails 3 I18n label_tag translation

Tags: internationalization, label, ruby-on-rails-3

One would think the following code would access I18n:

```
= label_tag(:person_name)
```

and look up en.helpers.label.person_name, or something of the sort. However, the rails code does not seem to use I18n whatsoever:

```
159:       def label_tag(name = nil, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
160:         options = content_or_options if block_given? && content_or_options.is_a?(Hash)
161:         options ||= {}
162:         options.stringify_keys!
163:         options["for"] = sanitize_to_id(name) unless name.blank? || options.has_key?("for")
164:         content_tag :label, content_or_options || name.to_s.humanize, options, &block
165:       end
```

so it seems the only option is to explicitly call `label_tag(:person_name, I18n.t(:person_name))`. This seems unnecessary, so am I missing something here or should I be working on a rails patch?  Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have asked the exact same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4479950/382818. Please delete one of the questions.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but these are actually different questions. One is specifically the use of f.label in a nested has_many relationship. This question concerns the use of label_tag, which is a method of Helpers::FormTagHelper, not Helpers::FormHelper.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this? I'm trying to avoid creating two entries in my localization files...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but no I never figured out a way.  I'm simply using `label_tag t(:person_name)`.

Comment: When using the `t` method with `label_tag` you may want to the use the `:scope` option on `t` to help DRY things up.

Answer (score 1):

`= label_tag(:person_name)` will not work. But you can use the `t()` method to get this to
work.

```
= label_tag(t(:person_name))
```

The translation can then be added:

Then in file `en.yml` :

```
en: 
  person_name: John
```

You could also tie the translation to the view it is in:

In `app/views/something/index.html.haml`

```
= label_tag(t('.person_name'))
```

would look for this translation in file `en.yml` :

```
 en
  something
    index
      person_name: John
```

Comment: Again, thanks for the response, but it is a no go. I don't expect label_tag to access any object (such as person) since the method is not called on a form object like f.label would be.

Comment: This doesn't work because then you get `<label for="Translation">Translation</label>` instead of `<label for="SymbolName">Translations</label>`.

Comment: You can supply the symbol first, then the t() method as the second argument to give a translated text value.