# i18n labels for nested models using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, nested-attributes, simple-form

If a project:

- has_many :tasks
- accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks

and I am using simple_form like so (simplified):

```ruby
simple_form_for @project do |f|
  f.input :project_name
  f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |j|
    j.input :task_name
  end
  f.submit
end
```

How would I internationalize the label for `:task_name`? I have tried quite a few combinations in my `simple_form.it.yml` file, such as:

```yaml
it:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      project:
        project_name: 'Nome progetto'
        task:
          task_name:  'Nome compito'
```

Haven't been able to find examples in the docs. Google points out a couple of apparently relevant closed issues:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/48

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/194

But so far I am at loss...

THANKS!
Giuseppe

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as your form accepts many tasks you should pluralize `task`. It works in simple_form:

```
it:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      project:
        project_name: 'Nome progetto'
        tasks:
          task_name:  'Nome compito'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the default Rails i18n.

```
it:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      task:
        task_name:  'Nome compito'
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in my case, but I need to try your suggestion again on a test, stripped down application.

Also see the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479950/rails-3-i18n-label-translation-for-nested-attributes-in-has-many-relationship

Comment: Simple_form by default will look for label translations for active record attributes. To use this is better - this way if you use those same labels on a table - it's all defined in one place, only use suggestion from accepted answer if you really want to customize that label on the form only. ( My guess it's not working for you if cause you have somethign funky with pluralization for tasks, OR !! you are using some server or gem that's caching your dev - the best place to test is in console. I keep forgetting that rails-dev-boost caches my dev - and keep running into same problem.)

Answer (score 3):

SimpleForm should fall back to `it.simple_form.labels.task.task_name` but it don't.

You can simulate it with some YAML 'hack'.

```
it:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      task: &task_labels
        task_name:  'Nome compito'
      project:
        project_name: 'Nome progetto'
        tasks:
          <<: *task_labels
```

You can even customize the labels of project's tasks, after the `<<: *task_labels` line.

Answer (score 0):

I wander if this is helpful:

```
activerecord.errors.models.[model_name].attributes.[attribute_name]
activerecord.errors.models.[model_name]
activerecord.errors.messages
errors.attributes.[attribute_name]
errors.messages
```